# R - argument of length zero in if() function

Tags: r, median

```
l_v2 = length(v2)
v2s = sort(v2)
max = 1
min = 1000
for (i in l_v2 /4 : l_v2 *3/4) {
  if( v2s[i]>max ) { max=v2s[i] }
  if( v2s[i]<min ) { min=v2s[i] }
}
```

Code's goal: Select 50% of `v2` around the median and determine the difference between the maximum and minimum value.

Error: `Argument is of length zero` in the `max if()` function. max and min are incorrect values as well, likely a consequence of this.

Comment: are `l_v2/4` and `l_v2*3/4` integers?

Comment: Try `(l_v2 %/%4) : (l_v2 *3 %/% 4)`. There is probably a way to do this in a more R-ish way ... Probably based on `quantile` ...

Comment: They are not guaranteed to be integers no. Thank you that did the trick. I apologize for the unorthodox code, I'm new to R

Comment: Based the short description of your goal, does `IQR(v2)` (i.e. the interquartile range) give the intended result? see: [IQR function](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/IQR.html)

Comment: Ah, clever! They are almost the same. IQR gives 16.725, my code gives 17

Comment: @Firkamon There are 9 different types of quantiles implemented in `quantile`. `IQR` uses type 7 by default, but you could change that ...